# giving if condition for time

Tags: r, if-statement

Is there any way we can give a condition statement in a if else loop as

```
 a= "06/28/2017 08:45"
 b= "06/28/2017 08:32"
 c= difftime(a,b,units="mins)
`if(a+30 > b)
 { 
  print("you are late")
  }else
  print("on time")`
```

my data frame is

```
      col1                       col2
  6/27/2017 11:00 
  6/27/2017 20:45            
  6/24/2017 19:30               6/24/2017 18:48
  6/27/2017 20:00               6/28/2017 3:16
  6/29/2017 18:30               
  7/4/2017 7:30
  6/24/2017 1:30               6/24/2017 0:21
  6/29/2017 10:00
  6/28/2017 16:30              6/28/2017 18:39
  7/2/2017 19:00
```

I'm getting error as

```
 `1.Error in if (a+30 > b) missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
  In Ops.factor(a+30 > b) :‘>’ not meaningful for factors
  2: In if (a+30 > b) { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`
```

What I'm trying to do is to add 30min to 'a' and compare it wih 'b' to determine if something is late or on time.

Comment: `a` and `b` are character, you need to convert them to date-time object with `strptime` or `as.Posixct` and then add 30 minutes to `a` which would be 30*60 seconds and then compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
a=mdy_hm("06/28/2017 08:45")
b=mdy_hm("06/28/2017 08:32")
c= abs(difftime(a,b,units="mins))
d=ifelse(30>c,"you are late","on time")
print(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you format your dates correctly and use a minus instead of a plus in the if statement, it works fine:

```
a= as.Date("06/28/2017 08:45", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
b= as.Date("06/28/2017 08:32", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

if(a-10 > b) { 
        print("you are late")
} else {
    print("on time")
}
```

Change the a-10 to a-30 and you will be late.

Comment: how to implement this on the columns? And are we adding 10 or 30 using the minus operator?

Comment: Can you please write that question a little more comprehensive? what is it you want to achieve?

Comment: I've 2 columns with date and time as rows and i want to implement this on them to know if it is late or on time

Comment: sorry I got the output with the same loop.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
a= mdy_hm("06/28/2017 08:20")
b= mdy_hm("06/28/2017 08:32")
if_else(a + minutes(30) > b, "you are late", "on time")
```

Comment: when I implement this on my columns it is showing NA in all the rows

Comment: Follow this example: df = data.frame(a= mdy_hm(c("06/28/2017 08:20", "06/28/2017 08:15")), b= mdy_hm(c("06/28/2017 08:32", "06/28/2017 08:55")));
if_else(df$a + minutes(30) > df$b, "you are late", "on time")